# Tkinter Frame size defined as a fraction of parent Frame size

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to build a simple UI in Tkinter, and I've run into a problem.  I create a custom Frame object as a tab in a Notebook in the overall application, and the custom Frame defines a grid containing a set of controls on the left, and another Notebook on the right.  The control Frame correctly gets set to be a third of the width of the parent Frame, but the Notebook starts as only half of the width.  If I click the button that creates more tabs and adds them to the Notebook, the Notebook's width expands until the control Frame becomes unusable.  How do I define things so that the control Frame is always exactly, say, 30% of the parent Frame width and the Notebook is 70% of the width, even if the parent Frame gets resized?

Root.py

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.ttk import *
    from tkinter import filedialog
    import os

    from IndexFrame import IndexFrame

    root = Tk()
    root.option_add('*tearOff', FALSE)
    root.title('Test')
    width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height))
    root.grid_propagate(0)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    menubar = Menu(root)
    root['menu'] = menubar

    menu_app = Menu(menubar)
    menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_app, label='App')

    tabs = Notebook(root)
    tabs.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

    def openIndex():
        dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
        tab = IndexFrame(root, dir)
        tabs.add(tab, text=os.path.split(dir)[1])
    menu_app.add_command(label='Open Index', command=openIndex)

    def closeApp():
        root.destroy()
    menu_app.add_command(label='Close', command=closeApp)

    menu_index = Menu(menubar)
    menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_index, label='Index')

    def closeIndex():
        tabs.forget(tabs.index('current'))
    menu_index.add_command(label='Close Index', command=closeIndex)

    menu_results = Menu(menubar)
    menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_results, label='Results')

    def closeResults():
        tabs.nametowidget(tabs.select()).closeResults()
    menu_results.add_command(label='Close Results', command=closeResults)

    root.mainloop()
```

IndexFrame.py (You may have to remove the Lucene code if you want to run this unless you have PyLucene installed)

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from tkinter.ttk import *
    from tkinterhtml import HtmlFrame
    import lucene
    from lucene import *

    from java.io import File
    from java.lang import Integer
    from org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard import StandardAnalyzer
    from org.apache.lucene.index import IndexReader, DirectoryReader
    from org.apache.lucene.search import IndexSearcher, BooleanClause
    from org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic import MultiFieldQueryParser
    from org.apache.lucene.store import FSDirectory

    from ScrollText import ScrollText

    class IndexFrame(Frame):#(PanedWindow):

        def __init__(self, parent, dirPath):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        lucene.initVM()
        analyzer = StandardAnalyzer()
        indexPath = File(dirPath).toPath()
        indexDir = FSDirectory.open(indexPath)
        reader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir)
        searcher = IndexSearcher(reader)

        self.grid_propagate(0)

        queryFrame = Frame(self)
        queryFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsw')

        self.resultsTabs = Notebook(self)
        self.resultsTabs.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nesw')

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3)

        label = Label(queryFrame, text="Contains " + str(reader.numDocs()) + " indexed documents")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='nesw')

        text = ScrollText(queryFrame)
        text.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='nesw')

        def save_btn():
            fname = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="Save query", filetypes=(("text files", "*.txt"),))
            if fname:
                file = open(fname, 'w')
                file.write(text.text.get('1.0', 'end'))
                file.close()
        save = Button(queryFrame, text='Save', command=save_btn)
        save.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

        def load_btn():
            fname = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Load query", filetypes=(("text files", "*.txt"),))
            if fname:
                text.text.delete('1.0', 'end')
                file = open(fname, 'r')
                text.text.insert('1.0', file.read())
                file.close()
        load = Button(queryFrame, text='Load', command=load_btn)
        load.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew')

        def clear_btn():
            text.text.delete('1.0', 'end')
        clear = Button(queryFrame, text='Clear', command=clear_btn)
        clear.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='ew')

        def search_btn():
            queryText = text.text.get('1.0', 'end')
            fields =["title", "abstract", "keywords"]
            flags = [BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD]
            query = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(queryText, fields, flags, analyzer)
            docs = searcher.search(query, Integer.MAX_VALUE)

            tab = Frame(self.resultsTabs)

            resultsLabel = Label(tab, text="{} => {} results".format(queryText, len(docs.scoreDocs)))
            resultsLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')

            htmlText = HtmlFrame(tab, vertical_scrollbar="auto")
            htmlText.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nesw')

            html = "<html>"
            doc = searcher.doc(docs.scoreDocs[0].doc)
            html += "<h2>Title: {}</h2></br>".format(doc.getField("title").stringValue())
            #html += "<h4>Abstract: {}</h4></br>".format(doc.getField("abstract").stringValue())
            html += "</html>"
            htmlText.set_content(html)

            self.resultsTabs.add(tab, text=str(len(docs.scoreDocs)))

        search = Button(queryFrame, text='Search', command=search_btn)
        search.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='ew')

        queryFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        queryFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=0)
        queryFrame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        queryFrame.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=0)
        queryFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        queryFrame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        queryFrame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        def closeResults(self):
        self.resultsTabs.forget(self.resultsTabs.index('current'))
```

ScrollText.py

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.ttk import *

    class ScrollText(Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            self.text = Text(self)
            self.text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

            yscroll = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.text.yview)
            yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nesw')
            self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)

            self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0)
```

I'm also happy to get general Python advice.  I don't have a lot of experience building Python applications that involve more than one file/class, so I'm certain that I'm doing a lot of stuff wrong (particularly sure that I'm not sub-classing correctly).

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There seems to be a lot of unrelated code in your question. Please try to reduce the code down to fewest lines necessary to duplicate the problem.

Comment: Read up on [When to use the Place Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) instead of `.grid()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.place()` manager.

The `.place()` manager is one of the three geometry managers in tkinter.

It has a lot of arguments, but I think there are 3 that you may need.

The first one is `relheight`. This stands for "relative height", and, true to it's name, it sets the height of the widget relative to the height of the master widget.

For example, if you set the `relheight` parameter to 0.6, then the height of the widget you set it to will stay to be 60% of the height of the master widget.

The second argument is `relwidth`. This one works in the same way as `relheight`, just dealing with the width instead of the height.

The last one is `anchor`. This one isn't as useful as the previous two, but in some cases it's very handy. `anchor` sets the position of the placement. For example, if `anchor` was "center", then the coordinate you specified in the place function with `relx` and `rely` will be in the center of that widget.

Of course, this is a very basic explanation, but the other parameters such as `relx` and `rely` are covered in the documentation.

Read up more about place [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm).

Hope this helps!